# Comparing collection keys in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

Wanted to see if RxJS has a quick / elegant way of doing this.

Suppose we have two different array of objects.  For example:

`A1`:

```
[{ name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
{ name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
{ name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
{ name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }]
```

`A2`:

```
[{ name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
{ name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
{ name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
{ name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }]
```

The keys we want to compare are identified by the `name` property.

I was thinking about just producing two arrays of all the names filtering out the duplicates, and then comparing them to make sure they are equal, but thought perhaps `RxJS` has a slick way of doing this and could also emit an observable of any names that don't have a match?

Comment: There's no operator for this. You can use `map` and compare it yourself.

Comment: If you are sure that the 2 arrays have always the same elements in the same order with respect to the key (e.g. the name in your example) you can look at the `zip` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try merging the two lists and then applying the `distinct` operator with a key selector function (to specify key is `"name"`) so that you get a stream of the de-duped items.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinct